# Click html link in iOS UIWebView do nothing

Tags: ios, hyperlink, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have `UIWebView` that load html content using `loadHTMLString` from core data. If i have html link (eg. `<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>`) in html content and click this link it does nothing. Absolutely nothing happen.

I tried to implement delegate method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` and when I print content of `request.URL` it returns `about:blank`.

I tried to to set in my `UIWebView`

```
webView.userInteractionEnabled = true
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.All
```

Do anybody knows what could be wrong??

Comment: Have you get the url with the following method `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('xyz').href"];   `

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it now and it returns "`http://www.google.com/`" which should be ok.

Comment: @marysmech : post an answer whatever is worked with you...

Answer (score 2):

Please try with the following code.
Implement the UIWebview Delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On **Swift 4.2**

You can try with the following code, must be implement **UIWebViewDelegate**

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebView.NavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == .linkClicked {
        if let url = request.url {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```